# How do I show that this quotient is a Noetherian Ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

What is the structure of $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ ?
How can I prove that it is Noetherian Ring?

**Edit:**
Here, $(X^2+Y^2-1)$ refers to ideal generated by the polynomial $p(X,Y)=X^2+Y^2-1$

Answer (score 3):

There is surjection from $\Bbb Z[X,Y]$, which is Noetherian by [Hilbert's basis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem).

Comment: But by Hilbert basis theorem, ring of polynomials is Noetherian. How can I prove that the above quotient is Noetherian ?

Comment: @user579315 you can prove separately that quotient of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian.

Comment: Ohk... Can you please point me to source where i can get the proof for "quotient of noetherian ring is noetherian".

Comment: [Second sentence of this proof](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FN).

Comment: Ohk..Cool :) Thank you